# How to make a sprite move with keyboard in java(libgdx)

Tags: java, keyboard, libgdx, sprite, 2d-games

i'm making a game for school motives, i have already made the sprite and the background(tiled map) my problem is how i can make the sprite move left, right, back and down using the keyboard, please guys help me as soon as possible here is my code:

```
public class LEVEL1 implements ApplicationListener, Screen {
private Music music;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture Sprite;
private Vector2 position;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
private OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {       
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    position.y = position.y - 5;

    // player Controls
    if(position.y < 0){
        position.y = 0;
    }

    //..................................................

    // renderer camera and map
    camera.update();
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();
    //...................................................

//tells the computer when to start drawing textures
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Sprite, position.x, position.y, 50, 50);
    batch.end();
    //...................................................

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 2920,950);

}

@Override
public void show() {    
    Sprite = new Texture("Sprite.png");
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    position = new Vector2(650, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    map = new TmxMapLoader().load("map1.tmx");

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

      music = Gdx.audio.newMusic((Gdx.files.internal("GameSound.mp3")));

        music.setLooping(false);
        music.setVolume(0.5f);
        music.play();
}

@Override
public void create() {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.position.set(width/2f, height/3f, 0); //by default camera position on (0,0,0)
    camera.update();


}

@Override
public void render() {
    if(Gdx.input.justTouched())
        music.play();


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    music.dispose();        
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: You should definitely google this, this is one of the most basic things in libGDX, so there's a bunch of resources online. For example, take a look at the sample project on the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

Comment: hi :) i've search every where, but i can't make my sprite to move with the keyboard, i'm also  new at programming, pls if u can help me,  help :)

Comment: It is literally explained step by step on the page I linked you.

Answer (score 1):

To react on input events you need to implement [`InputProcessor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html). It has the methods `keyDown` (called when a key is pressed) and `keyUp` (called when a key is released).
Those methods have an argument `keyCode`, which defines the int code of the pressed/released key.
So you need to override this 2 methods and depending on the keyCode you get, you should do something or not.
To move the player for example, you might keep a member `speed`, which you set, depending on the pressed/released key. In the `render` method you then need to update the position depending on the elapsed time (`delta`) and the `speed`.

To get the input event, you need to tell libgdx, that your `InputProcessor` should be the active one. This is done by calling `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(yourInputProcessor)`.

Also make sure to read the [Libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki), many of your questions will be answered there.

**EDIT**:
Some code:

```
public class Level implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {

    private int speedX;  // Speed in x direction
    private Vector2 position;  // Position

    private boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (keyCode == Keys.D) {
           result = true;
           speed += 5;
        }
        else if (keyCode == Keys.A) {
            result = true;
            speed -= 5;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean keyUp(int keyCode) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (keyCode == Keys.D) {
           result = true;
           speed -= 5;
        }
        else if (keyCode == Keys.A) {
            result = true;
            speed += 5;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
         position.x += speed*delta;

         // Render here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man :), can u please show me how my code will be after adding all this thing, i'm new at producing :) pls

Comment: I edited my answer. Pls don't just copy-paste the code, but think about it. It is important, that you understand the code, otherwise you won't learn a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here i make a little example of moving a sprite using keys (up,down, left,right)

you should find more details in libgdx wiki

```
public class Level1 implements ApplicationListener {


    Sprite sprite;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    float spriteXposition;
    float spriteYposition;

    @Override
    public void render() { 

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //tells the computer when to start drawing textures
        batch.begin();
        sprite.setPosition(spriteXposition, spriteYposition);
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        spriteControl();

    }

    public void spriteControl() {

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
            spriteYposition++;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
            spriteYposition--;
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
            spriteXposition--;
        }

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
            spriteXposition++;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void create() {

        sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("sprite.png")));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }
}
```